# Exportar JTable a extensiones .xlsx y .pdf

Tags: java, excel, pdf

Buen día, hice un JFrame Form el cual tiene que exportar un jTable a Excel y PDF. Ya me exporta pero exporta los 2 archivos al tiempo, entonces quiero que al seleccionar el filtro Excel en el FileChooser, me exporte solo en esa extensión, lo mismo con el pdf.

Les dejo el código de la exportación, gracias de antemano.

**Solucionado tras colocar** `if (nameExtension.equals("Documento PDF (*.pdf)"))`

```
  seleccionar.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Documento PDF (*.pdf)", "pdf"));
        seleccionar.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Libro de Excel (*.xlsx)", "xlsx"));
        seleccionar.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

        if (seleccionar.showDialog(null, "Exportar Archivo") == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            String nameExtension = seleccionar.getFileFilter().getDescription();

            // Exportar a PDF
            if (nameExtension.equals("Documento PDF (*.pdf)")) {
                try {
                    // We create the document and set the file name.        
                    // Creamos el documento e indicamos el nombre del fichero.
                    Document document = new Document();
                    try {
                        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(seleccionar.getSelectedFile() + ".pdf"));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {

                    }
                    document.open();

                    // First page (Primera pÃ¡gina)
                    Anchor anchor = new Anchor();
                    anchor.setName("");

                    // Second parameter is the number of the chapter (El segundo parámetro es el número del capí­tulo).
                    Chapter catPart = new Chapter(new Paragraph(anchor), 1);

                    Paragraph subPara = new Paragraph("");
                    Section subCatPart = catPart.addSection(subPara);
                    subCatPart.add(new Paragraph(""));

                    // Create the table (Creamos la tabla)
                    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(jTable1.getColumnCount());

                    // Now we fill the rows of the PdfPTable (Ahora llenamos las filas de PdfPTable)
                    PdfPCell columnHeader;
                    // Fill table columns header 
                    // Rellenamos las cabeceras de las columnas de la tabla.                
                    for (int column = 0; column < jTable1.getColumnCount(); column++) {
                        columnHeader = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(jTable1.getColumnName(column)));
                        columnHeader.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                        table.addCell(columnHeader);
                    }
                    table.setHeaderRows(1);
                    // Fill table rows (rellenamos las filas de la tabla).                
                    for (int row = 0; row < jTable1.getRowCount(); row++) {
                        for (int column = 0; column < jTable1.getColumnCount(); column++) {
                            table.addCell(jTable1.getValueAt(row, column).toString());
                        }
                    }
                    subCatPart.add(table);

                    document.add(catPart);

                    document.close();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.jTable1, "Your PDF file has been generated!(Â¡Se ha generado tu hoja PDF!)",
                            "RESULTADO", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } catch (DocumentException documentException) {
                    System.out.println("The file not exists (Se ha producido un error al generar un documento): " + documentException);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.jTable1, "The file not exists (Se ha producido un error al generar un documento): " + documentException,
                            "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
            // Exportar a EXCEL
            if (nameExtension.equals("Libro de Excel (*.xlsx)")) {
                File archivo;
                archivo = seleccionar.getSelectedFile();
                int cantFila = jTable1.getRowCount();
                int cantColumna = jTable1.getColumnCount();
                Workbook wb;
                wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
                Sheet hoja = wb.createSheet(" ");

                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < cantFila; i++) {
                        Row fila = hoja.createRow(i + 1);
                        for (int j = 0; j < cantColumna; j++) {
                            Cell celda = fila.createCell(j);
                            if (i == -1) {
                                celda.setCellValue(String.valueOf(jTable1.getColumnName(j)));
                            } else {
                                celda.setCellValue(String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(i, j)));
                            }
                            wb.write(new FileOutputStream(archivo + ".xlsx"));
                        }
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exportacion exitosa");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vuelve a intentarlo");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: puedes comentar mas como hiciste la exportación, disculpa que pida mucho ya que soy nuevo en java, comentes que librerías usaste para exportar a PDF. desde ya gracias

Comment: @JoséLuísFloresBendezu primero haga un form de registro, cada que registre se guarde en un jtable, ya cuando tenga la vista de la tabla con registros hace un boton exportar y en la función de ese boton hace lo del exportar. Para exportar a pdf utilice itextpdf

Comment: rayos justo venía a decirle que si ya había intentado usando if xD

Answer (score 0):

Podrías verificar la `extensión` del archivo y ahí poder verificar a que formato se exportará tu `jTable` , hice uso de una expresión regular para obtener la extensión , **si tienes una mejor forma  la reemplazas**

En tus case llamarías a tu `métodos` **exportar** dependiendo de la `extensión`.

Además uso una variable `booleana` para tener control cuando se elige una extensión desconocida o cuando no se elige nada.

```
boolean active=false;
  while(!active)
  {
    if (seleccionar.showDialog(null, "Exportar Archivo") == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       String extension = seleccionar.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath().split("\\.(?=[^\\.]+$)")[1];
       switch(extension){
           case "pdf" : System.out.println("EXPORT PDF");active=true;break;
           case "xlsx" : System.out.println("EXPORT EXCEL");active=true;break;
           default:
               active = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "EXTENSIÓN NO VÁLIDA , DESEA SELECCIONAR UNA EXTENSIÓN DIFERENTE?"
                       ,"MENSAJE ! ", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
       }
    }
   else
        active = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "NO SELECCIONO UN ARCHIVO, DESEA SELECCIONAR?"
                ,"MENSAJE ! ", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
  }
```

Comment: funciona siempre y cuando se ponga la extensión manualmente, pero quiero que al seleccionar el filtro me exporte a esa extensión.   Código de los filtros:                                                                                                                             public void AgregarFiltro() {
        seleccionar.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Documento PDF (*.pdf)", "pdf"));
        seleccionar.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Libro de Excel (*.xlsx)", "xlsx"));
        seleccionar.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    }

Comment: Podrías colocar todo dentro de un `do while (extensión.length()==0)` y así el ingreso de la extensión de vuelve obligatorio.

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda, ya lo pude corregir con `if (nameExtension.equals("Documento PDF (*.pdf)"))`